# FreeBSD, Boost, compiling fails

Tags: boost, freebsd

I am trying to compile some code on FreeBSD (not mine), which uses boost, but when i run the Makefile, i get the following errors:

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/boost `taglib-config --cflags` -fPIC -O3 -DBOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG -DNDEBUG -c -o Codegen.o Codegen.cxx
In file included from SubbandAnalysis.h:11,
                 from Fingerprint.h:12,
                 from Codegen.cxx:13:
MatrixUtility.h:12:42: error: boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp: No such file or directory
MatrixUtility.h:13:48: error: boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp: No such file or directory
In file included from SubbandAnalysis.h:11,
                 from Fingerprint.h:12,
                 from Codegen.cxx:13:
MatrixUtility.h:15: error: 'boost' has not been declared
MatrixUtility.h:15: error: 'ublas' is not a namespace-name
```

I did install boost, and the files `matrix.hpp`, etc. are indeed in the folder `/usr/local/include/boost/numeric/ublas/`.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-I/usr/local/include/boost` should be just `-I/usr/local/include`

As it is now, the compiler searches for /usr/local/include/boost/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp